# Selenium Web Driver returns Selector not visible

Tags: selenium, xpath, automation, webdriver, webautomation

I have a HTML page that looks like this. I have to click on a menu dropdown and click on its 6th item.

```
<li class="open">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle ">
        <i><img src="/cs/images/icon_01.jpg" alt=""></i>
        <span class="menu-text"> User Account Management </span>

        <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-down"></b>
    </a>
    <b class="arrow"></b>

    <!-- Account Analysis start -->
    <ul class="submenu nav-show active" id="useraccount" style="display: block;">
        <li class="">
            <a href="/cs/servlets/UserServlet?action=newAccountAnalysis&amp;isLogged=true">
                <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
                <span class="menu-text">Account Analysis</span>
            </a>
            <b class="arrow"></b>
        </li>
        <!-- Account Analysis end -->
        <!-- Delete User Account start -->
        <li class="">
            <a href="/cs/servlets/UserServlet?action=selectUserAccountToDelete&amp;isLogged=true">
                <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
                <span class="menu-text">Delete User Account</span>
            </a>

            <b class="arrow"></b>
        </li>
        <!-- Delete User Account end-->   
        <!-- Unlock/Re-activate User Account     start -->     
        <li class="">
            <a href="/cs/servlets/UserServlet?action=selectUserAccountToUnlock&amp;isLogged=true">
                <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
                <span class="menu-text">Unlock/Re-activate User Account</span>
            </a>

            <b class="arrow"></b>
        </li>
        <!-- Unlock/Re-activate User Account end -->
        <!-- De-activate User Account     start -->     
        <li class="">
            <a href="/cs/servlets/UserServlet?action=selectUserAccountToDeactivate&amp;isLogged=true">
                <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
                <span class="menu-text">De-activate User Account</span>
            </a>

            <b class="arrow"></b>
        </li>
        <!-- De-activate User Account end -->
        <!-- Update User Profile   start -->     
        <li class="">
            <a href="/cs/jsp/user/rsdUpdateUser.jsp">
                <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
                <span class="menu-text">Update User Account</span>
            </a>

            <b class="arrow"></b>
        </li>
        <!-- Update User Profile end -->
        <!-- Search RSD User start -->    
        <li class="">
            <a href="/cs/servlets/UserServlet?action=searchRsdUser&amp;isLogged=true">
                <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
                <span class="menu-text">Search RSD User</span>
            </a>

            <b class="arrow"></b>
        </li>
        <!-- Search RSD User end -->
    </ul>
</li>
```

I need to select the item "search RSD user" and for this I decided to use find element by xpath and I wrote the following xpath.

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"useraccount\"]/li[6]/a")).click();`

However I get the following

```
error.org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
```

I verified if my path is correct by testing the xpath from chrome's developer tools and path works fine however it does not work on webdriver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use explicit wait to make sure the element is visible before clicking on it

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"useraccount\"]/li[6]/a")));
element.click();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution @Guy but i'm still not clear on as to what makes driver "wait" for this tag. If you can point me to any documentation or help link that has an explanation it would be really helpful. i'm a novice on automation and i'm trying to learn. Thanks once again for the valuable help.

Comment: @CaRtY5532 The driver doesn't really waits. It sample the DOM every 500 milliseconds and check if the [expected condition](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) is met, in this case it will try to locate the element and check if it displayed and has height and width (you can see it in the link I attached). If it successful in the time limit (10 seconds in my answer) it will return the element. Otherwise it will throw `TimeoutException`.

Answer (score 0):

Use WebDriverWait to find the element.

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(WebDriverRefrence,TimeOut);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait (driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityofElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"useraccount\"]/li[6]/a")));

[Check this post](http://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/webdriverwait-selenium-webdriver/).